# $F[x]/\langle x^2\rangle$ is not an integral domain

Tags: ring-theory

The ring $F[x]/\langle x^2\rangle$ for an infinite field $F$ is an infinite commutative ring with identity which isn't a domain.

I'm still stuck in understanding why is it not a integral domain.i.e. which element it contains are non-zero zero divisors..Please help ...

Comment: The intuition for quotient rings should be that the elements of the ideal are "set to $0$" (made precise, this is the statement "$a+I=b+I$ if and only if $a-b\in I$"). So in this case, the construction of the ring explicitly declares the square of some element (that was at least non-zero before the quotient) to be zero - which gives you a clue as to where you could look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** For $p\in F[x]$ denote $\bar{p}=p+\langle x^{2}\rangle$. What
is $\bar{x}\cdot\bar{x}\,?$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\left(x+\left\langle x^2\right\rangle\right)^2=\overline 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Similar to $\mathbb{Z}/\langle 7^2 \rangle$.